# Query to find the average number of entries for the given hour range

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-5

I have the below-given query that should find the average number of entries for the given hour range, i.e. from 15:00 to 16:00.

This query is not working properly. How can I indicate the hour range (without date) and find the average number of entries per this range?

```
POST /myindex/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {"term": {"EventId": "11"}},
        {"term": {"EventType": "Type1"}}
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "range": {
        "date_range": {
            "field": "Datetime",
            "ranges": [
                { 
                   "from": "16:00-1H/H",
                   "to": "16:00/H" 
                }
            ]
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Should I use moving average? How?

I tried this, but I appreciate if someone can help me finish this query. I don't know if `"value_count" : { "field" : "EventHour"}` is the correct way to count the number of entries. How can I properly add the range of hours in this query?:

```
    POST /myindex/_search
    {
      "size": 0,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {"term": {"EventId": "11"}},
            {"term": {"EventType": "Type1"}},
{
          "script": {
            "script": "doc.date.date.getHourOfDay() >= min && doc.date.date.getHourOfDay() <= max",
            "params": {
              "min": 15,
              "max": 16
            }
          }
        }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "hourly_intensity": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "Datetime",
            "interval": "hour"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "count_of_events": {
              "value_count" : { "field" : "EventHour"}
            }
          }
        },
        "hourly_avg_count": {
          "avg_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "hourly_intensity>count_of_events" 
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself:

```
   POST /myindex/_search
    {
      "size": 0,
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {"term": {"EventId": "11"}},
            {"term": {"EventType": "Type1"}},
            {"term": {"EventHour": 15}}
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "hourly_intensity": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "Datetime",
            "interval": "hour"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "count_of_events": {
              "value_count" : { "field" : "EventHour"}
            }
          }
        },
        "avg_num_events_per_hour": {
          "avg_bucket": {
            "buckets_path": "hourly_intensity>count_of_events" 
          }
        }
      }
}
```